# How to match multiple routes in Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

I need to show a form, for two different URLs:

```
/customer/edit/15
```

or

```
/customer/edit/sales/john
```

I want to show the same form, for both of them. Either the customer id is provided, or the name of the department and the name of the employee.

How can I implement this in my page route?

I already have this:

```
@page /customer/{action}/{id?:long}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute`.
Here is a demo:

Pages/Customer/Edit.cshtml:

```
@page "/customer/edit/{id:long}"
@model RazorPageDemo.Pages.Customer.EditModel
@{
}
<h1>edit</h1>
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services
            .AddRazorPages()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
               
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/customer/edit", "/customer/edit/{department}/{employee}");
               
            });
            
        }
```

result:
[image]